# See javascript functions tooltip text in EJS file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ejs

When working in a normal .js file and you hover over a base javascript method, it shows you the syntax of the method and some text that explains what it does, the arguments and return value. I think pretty much all of you here know what I mean, but just for clarification purposes, for the array.includes() method its like this:

[image: Info-text of Prototype.Array.includes() on hover]

Now, currently I'm working on a project with EJS and I noticed that when hovering over e.g. the array.includes() method inside a  tag, it only shows the syntax for the function, like so:

[image]

Is it possible to see the text-tooltip of basic js functions in ejs files? The language mode when inside a ejs files is set to html and i have installed these extension regarding ejs:

- EJS language support (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DigitalBrainstem.javascript-ejs-support)
- EJS language support (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leonzalion.vscode-ejs)
- EJS Eval (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kevgl.ejs-eval)

Originally I was hoping that it just works like a .js file and to be honest I'm not that familiar with configuring extensions and IDEs so I'm not really sure what is related to this issue and what to do.